# Liquid Simulation: Volume decreasing throughout simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to blender and I'm taking a crack at fluid simulation for a project. I'm trying to simulate a translucent whiskey bottle being lifted up and then pouring the liquid into a glass (the liquid object behavior is geometry.)

Anyway, I have a few problems I've ran into and I just cant seem to work it out:

During the simulation, the volume of the liquid never seems to stay constant. Firstly, the liquid object produces more particles when baked than its original size, causing it to leak (I kinda "solved" this by scaling the fluid geometry object down. Should I have done this?) . Then, throughout the simulation, the liquid loses more than half of its volume inside the bottle.

I have tried multiple methods to attempt to fix this namely:

On the liquid domain:

- Lowering CFL number
- Increasing timesteps maximum and minimum
- Increasing the particle radius (1.0 - 1.3) and setting keyframes throughout the timeline
- Increasing narrow band width
- Increasing resolution division (32,64,128,256)
- Used APIC instead of FLUID sim method
- Applied transformation on all objects

None of these have worked so far and tbh I'm kinda losing my mind, especially with the 5 hour baking times. Is there a way I can optimise this?

I've seen topics about this posted years ago and they all seem to conclude it as a bug or give the solutions I have tried above.

Any help or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. I have also posted this question to the blender help subreddit but so far I have not received any help. Will update again if there's any solutions.

[image]